# Understanding the role of vertices in $D_{2n}$ in the definition of rigid motion

Tags: dihedral-groups

I'm trying to understand a paragraph from Keith Conrad's expository paper on the dihedral group. The paragraph is:

> Pick two adjacent vertices of a regular $n$-gon, and call them $A$ and $B$ as in the figure below. An element $g$ of $D_n$ is a rigid motion taking the $n$-gon back to itself, and it must carry vertices to vertices (**how are vertices unlike other points in terms of distance relationships with all points in the polygon?**) and $g$ must preserve adjacency of vertices, so $g(A)$ and $g(B)$ are adjacent vertices of the polygon.

The point I've bolded is what is causing me confusion. I can't figure out how vertices differ from other points. Is the idea that a symmetry has to send vertices to vertices, and adjacent vertices have to be mapped to adjacent vertices? I'm struggling to answer this in a way that ties back to the definition of a rigid motion.

Can someone help me to understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[We now have a definitive answer in the form of @kcd's comment below, so there is no need to read this answer. It was also more elaborate than it needed to be, because I misinterpreted the term 'polygon' to mean what is more accurately termed a 'solid polygon'. This usage does have some currency, at least according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon): "In contexts where one is
concerned only with simple and solid polygons, a *polygon* may refer
only to a simple polygon or to a solid polygon."]

Although I  don't know what Conrad has in mind, one possible definition is this: a **vertex** of a set $P$ - in a Euclidean plane $E,$ say - is a point $v \in P$ that does not lie in any "open line segment" with endpoints in $P.$

This property can be defined in terms of the distance function $d \colon E \times E \to E,$ $(x, y) \mapsto \|x - y\|_2$ - itself usually defined in terms of the Euclidean norm function $\|\cdot\|_2$ - as follows.

If $x$ and $y$ are points of $E,$ the **open line segment** $]x, y[$ - this is a temporary, *ad hoc* technical term, with an equally temporary notation - is the set of all points $z \in E \smallsetminus\{x, y\}$ such that $d(x, z) + d(z, y) = d(x, y).$

Thus, a vertex of $P$ is defined as a point $v \in P$ such that there do not exist distinct points $x, y \in P \smallsetminus \{v\}$ such that $d(x, v) + d(v, y) = d(x, y).$

By definition (see the footnote on page 1 of Conrad's paper), a **rigid motion** is a function $T \colon E \to E$ - it is necessarily a bijection, whose inverse is also a rigid motion - such that $d(Tx, Ty) = d(x, y)$ for all $x, y \in E.$

**Lemma.** If $T$ is a rigid motion of $E,$ and $P$ is a subset of $E,$ then for all $v \in E,$ the point $v$ is a vertex of the set $P$ if and only if $Tv$ is a vertex of the image set $TP = \{Tx : x \in P\}.$

*Proof.* Because $T$ is a bijection, it is enough to prove the "if" part. Equivalently: if $v$ is not a vertex of $P,$ then $Tv$ is not a vertex of $TP.$ Suppose, then, that $v$ is not a vertex of $P.$ By definition, there exist distinct points $x, y \in P,$ neither equal to $v,$ such that $d(x, v) + d(v, y) = d(x, y).$ Because $T$ is a bijection, the points $Tv, Tx, Ty$ of $TP$ are pairwise distinct. Also, because $T$ is a rigid motion,
$$
d(Tx, Tv) + d(Tv, Ty) = d(x, v) + d(v, y) = d(x, y) = d(Tx, Ty).
$$
Therefore, $Tv$ is not a vertex of $TP.$ $\square$

It follows that if $T$ is a rigid motion of $E$ that maps a set $P$ to itself, i.e., $TP = P,$ then a point $v$ is a vertex of $P$ if and only if $Tv$ is a vertex of $P.$ In other words, $T$ restricts to a permutation of the set of vertices of $P.$

In the case where $n$ is an integer $\geqslant 3,$ and $P$ is a regular $n$-gon, it is clear that the set of vertices of $P,$ when defined in this way, is what we would expect. (But it might be a little tedious to write out a strict proof.) If $s$ is the common length of all the sides of $P,$ then two vertices $v, w$ of $P$ are said to be **adjacent** if and only if $d(v, w) = s.$ It is clear that if $T$ maps $P$ to itself, then $v, w$ are adjacent if and only if $Tv, Tw$ are adjacent.

Comment: This is an alternative answer. (I'll post it as such, if requested.) It's shorter, simpler, and more likely to be what Conrad had in mind. But it's harder (for me, at least) to see that it captures the usual notion of a vertex of a regular polygon. If $(E,d)$ is a metric space, and $P\subseteq E,$ define the **diameter** of $P$ in the usual way as $\sup\{d(x,y):x,y\in P\}.$ If $P$ has diameter $r,$ define the **vertices** of $P$ as the set $$\{x\in P:(\exists y\in P)\,d(x,y)=r\}.$$ Every compact subset of $E$ has vertices in this sense.

Comment: Here is what Conrad had in mind. If $P$ is an arbitrary point on the polygon, then for all small $r > 0$, there are two different points $P_r'$ and $P_r''$ on the polygon at distance $r$ from $P$. When $P$ is *not* a vertex, $d(P_r',P_r'') = 2r$ for all small $r$. When $P$ is a vertex, $d(P_r',P_r'') < 2r$ for all small $r$. (Here $d$ is the usual metric on the plane.) So we can distinguish vertices of a polygon from non-vertices by distance properties of the points on the polygon.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this question: [how not both points can be on the polygon implies that every point on the polygon is uniquely determined by its distance from given two points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1510862/1086360) (This fellow too was going through the same paper)
And yes, symmetry implies adjacent vertices being mapped to adjacent vertices.